# Conditional assignment not working for possibly undefined variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partial-views, variable-assignment

I have this at the beginning of a rails view partial:

```
<% enabled = true unless defined?(enabled) %>
```

This is to handle cases when the calling view doesn't pass in the `enabled` local, by setting a default.

But `enabled` doesn't get set to true.

I'm aware that of the construct `enabled ||= true`, but I can't use that here because of the possibility that the passed-in value is `false`. That would get overwritten with `true`.

Comment: If the passed-in value is `false`, it would NOT get overwritten with `true` in case of `enabled ||= true`. Your answer is good but your logic behind asking this question is questionable at the least :)

Comment: @ARK `||=` will overwrite any falsy value. Here's a test that ought to print `[true, false, true]` if overwrite doesn't happen with `false`: `def testme(enabled); enabled ||= true; enabled; end; p [testme(true), testme(false), testme(nil)]`. It prints 3 `true`s.

Comment: Thanks for response. Interesting! I will definitely test this out and research why/how it happens. Interesting.

Comment: @ARK If you find this behavior surprising, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1554379) to get a better understanding of `||`. Note that `enabled ||= expression` is equivalent to `enabled = enabled || expression`.

Comment: I tested it in irb and understand what you are implying. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fixed it:

```
<%
  unless defined?(enabled)
    enabled = true
  end
%>
```

It appears this is happening because of how the ruby parser works.

The postfix conditional in the question came after the assignment code, and I think the parser caused the variable to spring into existence with a `nil` value, making `defined?` return false.

See [this ruby forum post](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/941686).

Comment: @user153138 I didn't necessarily post the question to ask for help. I posted it to help others. I didn't see anything information after Googling that specifically addressed this problem in a succinct way, so I'm hoping others will find it useful. Please comment on the merits of the question and the answer themselves, and not on the time difference.

Comment: @user153138 btw, see [this faq about self-answering](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a similar effect to what you were originally trying to do by combining `defined?` with the OR operator `||`:

```rb
defined?(enabled) || enabled = true
```

Example:

```rb
2.4.4 :001 > enabled
NameError: undefined local variable or method `enabled' for main:Object
    from (irb):1
        ...(etc.)
2.4.4 :002 > defined?(enabule) || enabled = true
 => true 
2.4.4 :003 > enabled
 => true 
2.4.4 :004 > enabled = false
 => false 
2.4.4 :005 > defined?(enabule) || enabled = true
 => true 
2.4.4 :006 > enabled
 => true
```