# Whats wrong with this if statement? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a reputation system where users get points if milestones (10, 100, 1000, ...) are archieved. I have this if statement line:

```
if (before_points < ((10 || 100 || 1000 || 10000 || 100000 || 1000000))) && (after_points >= ((10 || 100 || 1000 || 10000 || 100000 || 1000000)))
```

It should return true if the points where either less than 10 or 100 or 1000 ...before, and if the points were more or equal to either 10 or 100 or 1000 ... afterwards.

It works if it was below 10 before, and more than 10 afterwards, and I am not quite sure if it works with 100, but it doesnt work if the points were below 1000 before and more than 1000 afterwards.

Is this the correct way to do this? Is it better to do this with a switch/case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more compact way you could do it...

```
[10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000].any?{|n| before_points < n && after_points >= n}
```

That expression will return `true` if a boundary is crossed, or `false` otherwise

Comment: Great, glad it helped! If you want to vote my answer up I won't argue. :)

Answer (score 2):

That's not really how logic operation work. The statement:

```
(10 || 100 || 1000 || 10000 || 100000 || 1000000)
```

will evaluate to `10`. The `||` operator between 2 or more numbers will return first non-`nil` value, in this case that's `10`, the first value. [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554340/understanding-the-or-operator-in-if-conditionals-in-ruby).

And even if that weren't the case, if the `before_points < 10` is true, the `before_points < 1000000` would also be true and if only `before_points < 1000000` was true, the if statement would still execute just the same as with `before_points < 10`, so the logic would be wrong.

Depending on what you want to solve, you could either use [`case`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-case) or define your milestones in array and iterate values 10,100,...,1000000, setting new  milestone each time the condition is still true.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is wrong.

```
if (before_points < ((10 || 100 || ...
```

will first evaluate the part

```
10 || 100
```

which will always return `10` because 10 evaluates to truthy, hence this line

```
if (before_points < ((10 || 100 || 1000 || 10000 || 100000 || 1000000))) && (after_points >= ((10 || 100 || 1000 || 10000 || 100000 || 1000000)))
```

is effectively the same of

```
if (before_points < 10) && (after_points >= 10)
```

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but it's probably better to use a case (this is just an example)

```
case
  when before_points < 10 && after_points >= 10
  # ...
  when before_points < 100 && after_points >= 100
  # ...
  else
  # ...
end
```

Comment: yes, i got it now thanks ... stupid thinking fail of mine, i will use a case