# Compact if with OR statement doesn't trigger

Tags: ruby

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554340/understanding-the-or-operator-in-if-conditionals-in-ruby) I now do

```
hostname = %x{hostname}

if ['staging', 'prod', 'jlpc'].include? hostname
  puts "yes"
end
```

My Linux hostname is `jlpc` but it doesn't print out `yes`.

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
%x{hostname}
# => "hostname\n"
```

Solution:

```
puts "yes" if ['staging', 'prod', 'jlpc'].include? hostname.chomp
```

Comment: Stray ` at the end there.

Answer (score 3):

I tried on my machine and that line appends a `\n` at the end of my hostname. So, try

```
hostname = %x{hostname}.rstrip
```

Comment: While not wrong, `chomp` is the conventional method here. A hostname should not have spaces in it.