# What does || between methods mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def respond_to?(method, include_private = false)
  super || @subject.respond_to?(method, include_private)
end
```

`||` is an `or` operator, so what does `||` between methods mean?

Will it always call `super` unless `super` returns nil then evaluate `@subject.respond_to` because of  short-circuiting for the `||` operator?

Edit: I think my question is not a duplicate because I know how the '||' operator work from other programming languages. I know what short-circuiting is. I just have never seen it used with just two methods without if statements involve.

Comment: Yep, that's basically correct. Except that `false` is a falsey value too.

Comment: That is correct, if the inherited/parent class does define respond_to or if it returns nil or false, then `@subject.respond_to?` would be evaluated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding the "||" OR operator in If conditionals in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554340/understanding-the-or-operator-in-if-conditionals-in-ruby)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `||` operator means the same regardless of how complex the expressions are on each side of it.

`A || B` means:

- evaluate `A`
- if `A == false` or `A == nil`

  - evaluate `B`
  - return the value of `B` as the value of the `A || B` expression
- otherwise return the value of `A` as the value of the `A || B` expression

Comment: `A == 0` is truthy