# Case statements: multiple variables with multiple possibilities for each variable

Tags: ruby

At first I thought this syntax worked but it seems `when` will only check the first value of the groups, if any of the first values fail it will return locked. to bad the `or` operand doesn't work here.

```
def lock(a,b,c,d)
  case [a,b,c,d]
    when[(3||5||7), 2, (5||6), (8||9||0)]
      "unlocked"
    else
      "locked"
  end
end

lock(3, 2, 5, 8)
lock(5, 2, 5, 0)
lock(5, 2, 6, 8)
lock(7, 2, 5, 8)
lock(7, 2, 6, 9)
```

I could do an if else statement for each variable, but i was hoping there was a way to do a case statement without having to make multiple when statements.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how case statements work; they compare the object in the case clause (in your case, `[a,b,c,d]`) to the object in each of the when clauses using the equality operator.

Comment: note that the thing in your when clause is simply an array that's going to evaluate to `[3, 2, 5, 8]`, not something that's magically going to lazily match to a variety of arrays

Comment: Your comment cleared things up for me. I thought `when` functioned like if else statements. So what your saying is it is really just doing `case  object` == `when object`? 

If so it's interesting that `||` doesn't throw some kind of syntax error. I think thats why I thought it was possible.

Comment: the or operator doesn't throw a syntax error because that's perfectly valid syntax; `3 || 5` simply evaluates to `3`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1554379/1810460

Answer (score 2):

I'll opt to loop the array instead of using a `case` statement, like this:

```
def lock(a,b,c,d)
  combination = [[3,5,7], [2], [5,6], [8,9,0]]
  attempt     = [a,b,c,d]

  combination.each_with_index do |position, i|
    return "locked" unless position.include?(attempt[i])
  end

  "unlocked"
end
```

Outputs:

```
lock(3, 2, 5, 8)
#=> "unlocked"

lock(5, 2, 5, 0)
#=> "unlocked"

lock(5, 2, 6, 8)
#=> "unlocked"

lock(7, 2, 5, 8)
#=> "unlocked"

lock(7, 2, 6, 9)
#=> "unlocked"

lock(1, 2, 3, 4)
#=> "locked"
```

---

Why your solution fails?

Just as [Hamms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1810460/hamms) pointed out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377745/case-statements-multiple-variables-with-multiple-possibilities-for-each-variabl/44377910#comment75756630_44377745), the `when` with `[(3||5||7), 2, (5||6), (8||9||0)]` evaluates to `[3, 2, 5, 8]`. That is because each expression in parenthesis is evaluated first, so, breaking it down, it would be:

```
(3 || 5 || 7)
#=> 3

2
#=> 2

(5 || 6)
#=> 5

(8 || 9 || 0)
#=> 8
```

This is because `||` is evaluating if value is *truthy*, that is, is neither `nil` nor `false`. As soon as the expression gets to a *truthy* value, it will return that value and look no further. So any number will evaluate as *truthy*, and you will always get the first number of each expression as a result.

Back to your `case` statement, it is the exact same thing as writing it like:

```
case [a,b,c,d]
when [3, 2, 5, 8]
  "unlocked"
else
  "locked"
end
```

Now consider that a `case` statement will evaluate if the object in `case` is equal with the one in each `when`. So in, your case will be something like:

```
[a,b,c,d] === [3, 2, 5, 8]
```

Which will return `true` (and `"unlocked"`) only when you call `lock(3, 2, 5, 8)`.

Also consider that you could use multiple values with `when`, so using something like this will work:

```
case [a,b,c,d]
when [3, 2, 5, 8], [5, 2, 5, 0] then "unlocked"
else "locked"
end
```

In which `when` will be equivalent to doing:

```
[a,b,c,d] === [3, 2, 5, 8] || [5, 2, 5, 0]
```

Comment: That is clever! thanks I'll consider it. It's just I'm trying to gain more understanding of `case` statements because I never use them.

Comment: I was just writing the same and I think this is the best possible answer.

Comment: @WolfgangTruong Check updated answer, i hope it helps get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

As has been explained by others, this problem does not lend itself to the use of a case statement.

Since the variables appear to be digits, you could convert them to strings and use a regular expression.

```
def lock(entry, valid)
  r = /#{valid.map { |a| '['+a.join('|')+']' }.join }/
  entry.join.match?(r) ? 'unlocked' : 'locked'  
end
```

Suppose

```
valid = [[3, 5, 7], [2], [5, 6], [8, 9, 0]]
```

We compute the following regular expression for this value of `valid`:

```
r #=> /[3|5|7][2][5|6][8|9|0]/
```

Try it:

```
lock([3, 2, 5, 8], valid) #=> "unlocked"
lock([5, 2, 5, 0], valid) #=> "unlocked"
lock([5, 2, 6, 8], valid  #=> "unlocked"
lock([7, 2, 5, 8], valid) #=> "unlocked"
lock([7, 2, 6, 9], valid) #=> "unlocked"
lock([5, 2, 4, 0], valid) #=> "locked"
```