# Ruby - replace a letter for another Explanation for my code

Tags: ruby, string, split

I got to solve the problem I was trying to solve, but the thing is that I am not sure why it worked, I just started adding methods.

So if anyone could explain why worked:

```
def replace(string1, letter_a, letter_b)
  
  replacements = {letter_a => letter_b}

#this is the part I am not sure why is working:
   
initial_string.split('').map{|i| replacements[i] || i}.join
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I recommend to use built-in methods [`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub) or [`String#tr`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-tr)

```rb
string.gsub(%r{#{replaceable_letter}}, replacing_letter)

"abcdef".gsub(/a/, "b") # => "bbcdef"
```

```rb
string.tr(replaceable_letter, replacing_letter)

"abcdef".tr("a", "b") # => "bbcdef"
```

Instead of `initial_string.split('').map` you can use `initial_string.each_char.map`

---

Explanation of your code:

```
replacements = {letter_a => letter_b}
```

is hash where replaceable letter is key and replacing letter is value

For example `{ "a" => "b" }`

Than you split your string to chars array

After that map over this array

For every char you check the hash, for example:

```
replacements["a"] # => "b"
replacements["c"] # => nil
```

If hash has such key, you take replacing letter, if not take origin letter. Compare and [read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1554340/10608621) about `||` operator:

```
nil || "f" # => "f"
"b" || "a" # => "b"
```

And finally join new array